# Android build Error on OSX 10.8.5: cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together

Tags: android, c++, macos, cp, omap

I'm trying to compile Android FS, on OSX 10.8.5, and I'm getting an error that seems related to the fact that the build is being done on OSX.

I did all the brew installations and the compilation is being done on a case-sensitive FS,
yet I'm getting the following:

> target arm C++: libwebrtc_apm <= out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebrtc_apm_intermediates/proto/external/webrtc/src/modules/audio_processing/test/unittest.pb.cc
>   Symlink: out/target/product/generic/system/vendor/lib/libbltsville_cpu.so -> ./libbltsville_ticpu.so
>   Symlink: out/target/product/generic/system/vendor/lib/libbltsville_ticpu.so -> ./libbltsville_ticpu.2.1.0.0.so
>   Install: out/host/darwin-x86/bin/minigzip
>   cp: the -R and -r options may not be specified together.
>   make: *** [out/target/product/generic/system/vendor/lib/libbltsville_ticpu.so] Error 1
>   make: *** Deleting file `out/target/product/generic/system/vendor/lib/libbltsville_ticpu.so'
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Any ideas?

I know that -R can solve this issue, but the build is being done by scripts and it'll be very hard to change all the spots where -avr will be -avR!! 
I'm looking for a way to replace the cp command to a more linux like command....

Answer (score 0):

So I got an answer for this conundrum:

The Makefile & main.mk located in build/core

Are the rogue files that made the trouble, hope this'll help someone.